# Save textarea as session and echo without visible line-break format

Tags: php, session, formatting

I'm echoing out a multi-lined session string into a textarea if it's set:

```
<textarea><?php if (isset($_SESSION['saved_text'])) { echo nl2br($_SESSION['saved_text']); } ?></textarea>
```

Such as:

```
"Line 1
Line 2
Line 3"
```

And when it echoes out the session into the textarea it comes back with:

```
"Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3"
```

Yet I want it how it was formatted in the string, with the line-breaks, but not explicitly showing them as "\n" etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need `nl2br` for displaying new lines it in textarea.

```
<textarea><?php if (isset($_SESSION['saved_text'])) { echo $_SESSION['saved_text']; } ?></textarea>
```

This will work.
or you can use `htmlspecialchars()` if the text contains some special characters:

```
<textarea><?php if (isset($_SESSION['saved_text'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['saved_text']); } ?></textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

It seems the `\r\n` have bee escaped before saving in DB and now they are just characters of the text so to remove them you need to remove them as an character you can use `str_ireplace()` for this

```
<textarea><?php if (isset($_SESSION['saved_text'])) { echo str_ireplace("\\r\\n", "\r\n", $_SESSION['saved_text']); } ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Strangely neither work and still give me the same result as mentioned

Comment: P.s. the session comes from the same textarea

Comment: Probably `\n\r` are saved in text by escaping them try echoing `$_SESSION['saved_text']` normally and see what it prints(view source of page).

Comment: I mean the string when saved probably new lines were escaped as `\\r\\n` and now `\r\n` is stored as an string.

Comment: Updated My answer Hopefully it will help.:)